# sequelize postgres install dependency error with sqlite dialect

Tags: sqlite, electron, sequelize.js

I want to use sqlite database with electron, sequelize and sqlite database but I get postgres dependancy install error :

```
These dependencies were not found:

* pg-hstore in ./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/hstore.js
* tedious in ./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/query.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save pg-hstore tedious
```